# Android Intercepting POST Requests from Webview

Tags: android, post, webview

I have an android app that presents a secure form for verification. After the verification the server post's the data (necessary for the app).

I have a specific requirement not to host a PHP / JSP page to receive this POST and then redirect to the app.

I want to give the Authentication server a Dummy URL to Post its Data and then capture the HTTP POST and Data from the Webview in my app.

I went through lot of links and also noticed that it is a known android issue. (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9122)

Is there a way around this?

Comment: what do you want exactly? Like you want user should login through Webview and after login it should redirect to your application.